# Conditional typing with generic types

Tags: typescript

Given some types that looks like this

```
type Priority = "HIGH" | "MED" | "LOW";

type Task = {
title: string;
desc: string;
priority: Priority;
}

interface Edit<T> {
    param: T;
    change: T extends "title" | "desc"
        ? string
        : T extends "priority"
        ? Priority
        : never;
}

export type ParamsType<T> = T extends "add"
    ? Add
    : T extends "help"
    ? Help
    : T extends "edit"
    ? Edit<keyof Task>
    : never;
```

used in a function like this

```
exec<T extends Params>(command: T, args: ParamsType<T>) {
    // console.log(this);
    switch (command) {
        case "add":
            // call add
            break;
        case "edit":
            // call edit
            break;
     }
}
```

How can I get type inference for change based on a call like this?

```
schedule.exec("edit", {param: "priority", change: "notintype"}
```

I am getting type inference based on the value passed as the first parameter so how could I adapt that to getting the change to be typed as well?

Comment: Please create a [mre], perhaps using [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably get the behavior you want by rewriting `Edit` to distribute over unions, so `Edit<'title' | 'desc' | 'priority'>` is evaluated as `Edit<'title'> | Edit<'desc'> | Edit<'priority'>`, which will provide the proper type checking.

To have `Edit` distribute over unions, you can convert it to a type definition and introduce a dummy conditional (see [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types)):

```
type Edit<T> = T extends any ? {
    param: T;
    change: T extends "title" | "desc"
        ? string
        : T extends "priority"
        ? Priority
        : never;
} : never
```

This will allow calls like

```
schedule.exec("edit", {param: "priority", change: "HIGH"})
schedule.exec("edit", {param: "title", change: "Title"})
```

but fail with a type error on

```
schedule.exec("edit", {param: "priority", change: "notintype"})
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggJnKBeKBvA+gLigcgIYI4C+AUKJFABIQA2YyaWuAFrWMWeNAAp4BOeALYBnBvkJQAPrghwAlsBwlOFbnzkB7daAYAiSgEkA4pV1SougLIBRACJnpugDIB5AOq6A3MvLQAKnjCANYMqCRQEVDACjQQ2MLA6gB2AObekVBwEMIAxvGJcqnpkWDqWgog2Gqa2iDepCrQ1vLAADx+AHwMflAQAB7AEElwonhJIFAA-GjhJfxC2H7FETnMYylxUD39g8OiutHAsQ4WWbm6sxkR0wnJKZdXi70DQyMWpTUVF1eR09XloAeGWwSQgADcIHx6lAQeDIcp+mAtMAolwoLwBCI-Fx2l0UNsXnsLAQ4N9frAEA8njtXvtWHQydcqGwqVtnrs3rpZApGVMoM0FK0ghAQBoAGZbQJBDqs0EQqHKMUAVySOWiGiSzwgOXa7Np6PmIg6AAochpBIIxnBFgAaKD8FLCKqG4TYyC4gCUMwyAHofVAzUlhBpYgA6GgaFLG4DMOTCD3LKDCADuClWUFN5stwy9YR+K0C0F0JN0mCB+b9AbwNBo9sp+auACM+BA8EFExkcoWLNzgKXyz9K12a70WgOmy22x3SA1+trjVyWro7agwIbsLoPgCQMuA2tUpt9MZTEQvZWXEESHOcgve7vV+uLIdjnbVutD34YhBdKeoOfL1efTzouPIrmumIblutS7m+B4bkkGjREkvg-me-rWHwfBaCQQA)